# Regex not replacing text in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the specific code :

```
<script>

$.fn.revert = function(){
return this.each(function() {
var txt = $(this).html().replace(/<span class="gradientizer-done" style='color:rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)>.<\/span>/g,'');
$(this).html(txt);
});
};

</script>
```

And this code :

```
<p class="grad2" one="ffffff" second="000000">
<span class="gradientizer-done" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)"> </span>
<span class="gradientizer-done" style="color:rgb(219,219,219)">H</span>
<br>
<span class="gradientizer-done" style="color:rgb(109,109,109)">l</span>
</p>
```

Basically, the revert function intended to change all the `gradientizer-done` class to text , that is I expect the follow result when running revert on `$(".grad2").revert()`:

```
<p class="grad2" one="ffffff" second="000000">
 H<br>l</p>
```

But i see no change in `<p></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put a single quote after `style=` attribute instead of double quotes and also you forget to put  double quotes at the end of `style` attribute.

```
$(this).html().replace(/<span class="gradientizer-done" style="color:rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)">.<\/span>/g,'');
                                                              ^                                    ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just noted that I also forgot the capture group and $1

Comment: capturing group? where? your regex doesn't have any capturing group.

Comment: Am saying i forgot to add that to make my function work properly.. Nvm

Answer (score 2):

Better solution would be:

```
var $container = $(".grad2");
$container.find(".gradientizer-done").each(function(){
  $(this).after($(this).text())
  $(this).remove()
})
```